# Azure Rest API - Create Web App - Bad Request

Tags: rest, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am attempting to consume the Azure REST API to Create a new Web App [as documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/createorupdate).

I am using an `Authorization` = `Bearer xxxx` token created with the Scope and Resource of `https://management.azure.com/`.

The Registered App has the Microsoft Graph Api permission `Sites.Manage.All` and `Application.ReadWrite.All`.

I am doing a PUT to `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subID}/resourceGroups/{resGrp}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{newName}?api-version=2016-08-01`

I am specifying a content type of `application/json` with the following body:

```
{
    "location":"Central US",
    "properties":
    {
        "cloningInfo":
        {
            "sourceWebAppId":"subscriptions/{subID}/resourceGroups/{resGrp}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{cloneFromName}",
            "overwrite":true,
            "ignoreQuotas":true,
            "correlationId":"some random text??"
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried this similar body

```
{
    "location":"Central US",
    "properties.cloningInfo":
    {
        "sourceWebAppId":"subscriptions/{subID}/resourceGroups/{resGrp}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{cloneFromName}",
        "overwrite":true,
        "ignoreQuotas":true,
        "correlationId":"some random text??"
    }
}
```

I am able to successfully call List Sites specified at [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/list).

I assume I either have the wrong Api Permissions, or I am missing some required information in the body.

Comment: Did my answer solve your issue?

Comment: Well, you answered at 10pm my time and I was sleeping.  I am actually looking at it right now though.  I'll certainly follow general StackOverflow procedure and update your answer ASAP.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't realize this. Just take your time and let me know if you need further assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed ServerFarmId in the body, the body should be

```
{
    "location":"Central US",
    "properties":
    {
        "cloningInfo":
        {
          "sourceWebAppId":"{Resource ID of the webpp you want to clone}",
            "overwrite":true,
            "ignoreQuotas":true,
            "correlationId":"correlationId1"
        },
      "ServerFarmId":"{Resource ID of the associated App Service plan}"
    }
}
```

Besides, you need to confirm if your service plan supports clone app feature. Clone app is a feature that is only available to apps hosted on Standard App Service Plans. When you click Clone App on Azure portal, you will find the tip.
[image]

You can also find more details in the response.
[image]

Comment: It actually seems like the kicker for what I was missing was `"kind":"app"`.  But even with that, cloning still doesn't work.  I assume what you're saying about Plan level is true.  But I also can't find any documentation on that.  Also, since this is initial proof of concept work, and because I can't validate what you said since I can't find documentation, I'll up-vote you for leading me in the right direction. But I can't mark it as an answer until I either get a go-ahead to test in a Production Service Plan, or if I find some documentation validating what you're saying.

Comment: @Suamere Hi Suamere, when you click Clone App on Azure portal, you will find the tip. I have updated the answer. You can check that.

Comment: @Suamere Do you have any other concern regarding this?

Comment: Weird that the actual App Service Plan doesn't document that, but the feature says it is included in that app service plan.  I verified that.  Thank you for pointing me there.